# Paperclip: the default functionality when you enter an imaeg URL is for the image to download... how do I change it to just open in a new tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Paperclip image urls have ?395762034287346 after them.. does that affect it in anyway?

I don't know why the default isn't to just open the image in a new tab... no one downloads images anymore... srsly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.url` method for paperclip objects is no more than a simple URL, you need to enclose this within appropriate tags for your requirements, e.g. `<a href="<%= img.url %>" target="_blank"><img.../></a>`

Answer (score 1):

This is information about version of the image. Bowser will use it to know if it should download image from server or use the one previously cached.